# Debian: WLAN associated, but not pinging

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I have a brand new base install of Debian Lenny.

```
iwconfig
```

shows that I am associated with my home router over Wifi.

```
dhclient wlan0
```

gives me

```
bound to 192.168.1.121
```

But

```
ping google.com
```

gives no response, and

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

(my router's IP) gives the response

```
Destination Host Unreachable
```

And by the way, as soon as a re-plug in my wired Ethernet, ping and everything else work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that your dhcp server is not sending the gateway information. Check it out with the `route` command. You may configure it yourself just to check it out:

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

Then try to re-ping.